# Regular expression for everything between two characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression which allows me to remove tags in a string. These tags always look like this: `{...}`. 
I've tried `\{.*\}` so far but unfortunately this won't work if these tags occur two times. For Example: `{123} Hello {asdas}`. The entire line would be deleted since it starts with a { and end with a }. So, how can I avoid this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: \{.*?\} could do it, it won't match greedy which is the default, i.e. it will only match until the next \}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\{[^}]*\}
```

would probably do it.

An opening bracket, followed by any number of anything besides a closing bracket, followed by a closing bracket.

Comment: @KeithNicholas depends on your definition of nicer I suppose. It might be a little bit cleaner looking, but I doubt it's as performant.

Comment: Phillip's answer made me curious about the performance and there actually might be a big performance gap between those two solutions, see [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance). Learned something today.

Comment: @Boris nice link. That was basically my thinking when I wrote the comment to Keith